# Interstellar reddening for Cepheids

Tags: photometry, cepheids, extinction

How were interstellar reddening values for cepheid first calculated?

I mean, other than using the derived equation to get extinction-corrected magnitude of Cepheids, I want to know how to drive them independently from measured raw data (maybe V, B-band colors, etc).

Comment: Can you clarify - are you looking for redshift values as seen from Earth?